# Apache server repeatedly spinning if I try to retrieve files or check if folder exists

Tags: java, apache

I am creating a micro service where my application will go to `Apache Server` to get files and folder-contents.

Not all the time, but very frequently, my `Apache Server` just spins when I try to see if file/folder exists:

```
return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
```

or when I try to open connection:

```
c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

And I end up restarting service.

I can clearly access it by entering URL manually and get a `200 response code`.

I configured Apache to `allow Index view` for these files and folders.

Sometimes, when I type full path to a file using IP address, it spins also.... I find this very strange.

I don't know why this would happen... Any ideas?

```
Version: 2.4.23 win64 VC14
```

Comment: Not nearly enough details. all the code shows is you checking a response code. That will NOT cause apache to spin... by definition if you're getting a response code, then apache's already sent a response.